# why does the php function "sqlsrv_query" only work with 2 parameters sometimes but will need 4 other times?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm running IIS with SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2012 R2 and I have 2 php pages:

- The main page has 2 fieldsets, the first one displaying a database table by means of a `SELECT` sql statement. The second contains a form to pass data to a second php page.
- The second php page receives the data from the form and executes an `UPDATE` sql statement so that a new row is added to the database table using the values received from the form.

The code for the main page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
 <legend align="left">Administraci&oacuten</legend>
 <div>
  <fieldset style="height:250px; overflow:scroll;">
   <legend align="left">List</legend>
   <center>
   <?php

   $servername="server2012\SQLEXPRESS";
   $connect=array("Database"=>"Tienda","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"ciclo.01");
   $conn=sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connect);
   $sql="select * from almacen";
   $res=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
   echo "<table border='1' width='100%'>";
   echo "<tr><td><b>PRODUCTO</b></td>
             <td><b>CODIGO</b></td>
             <td><b>PRECIO</b></td>
             <td><b>ALMACEN</b></td>
             <td><b>EXISTENCIAS</b></td>
         </tr>";
    while ($linea=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo "<tr>
            <td>$linea[0]</td>
            <td>$linea[3]</td>
            <td>$linea[1]</td>
            <td>$linea[2]</td>
            <td>$linea[4]</td>
         </tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

    ?>
    </center>
   </fieldset>
   <a href="almacen.php">
    <input type="button" value="Refresh" style="float:right">
   </a>
 </div>

 <div style="float:left; width:50%;">
  <fieldset>
   <legend align="left">Insert</legend>
   <form action="insercion.php" method="post">
   <table>
    <tr><td>C&oacutedigo</td><td><input type="text" name="cod"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Producto</td><td><input type="text" name="pro"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Precio</td><td><input type="text" name="pre"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Almacen</td><td><input type="text" name="alm"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Existencias</td><td><input type="text" name="exi"></td></tr>
   </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Insert" style="float:right;">
   </form>
  </fieldset>
 </div>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

The main page succesfully executes the SQL statement and prints the table.

The code for 2nd page (containing the `UPDATE` statement):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<?php

$cod=$_POST['cod']; 
$pro=$_POST['pro']; 
$pre=$_POST['pre'];
$alm=$_POST['alm'];
$exi=$_POST['exi']; 

$servername="server2012\SQLEXPRESS";
$connect=array("Database"=>"Tienda","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"ciclo.01");
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connect);
$sql="insert into almacen values('$pro','$pre','$alm','$cod','$exi')";
$params=array();
$options=array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$res=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);
//$res=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
$rows=sqlsrv_num_rows($res);

echo "<p>$rows row inserted</p>";
echo "<a href='almacen.php'><input type='button' value='Return'></a>";

?>

</center> 
</body>
</html>
```

This second page works as it is, commenting out the original `sqlsrv_query()` containing 2 parameters and adding the lines `$params=array();`
and `$options=array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);` so that a `sqlsrv_query()` with 4 parameters can be used instead.

So what's the reason the sqlsrv_query in the main page works with only 2 parameters but the one in the second page fails with 2 parameters? 
(the output message on the second page will be `row inserted` instead of `row inserted` and after returning to the main page, the table will not contain the new row).

This also seems to be the case if I change the form in the main page so that it only contains 1 field and I change the `UPDATE` sql statement in the second page to a `DELETE` statement that will use the primary key value passed through the single-field form in the main page.

Basically, I would like to know what the lines `$params=array();`
and `$options=array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);` do and why they don't seem to be always necessary for sqlsrv_query function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you have PHP's error reporting enabled - always when developing code, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.  And following calls to `sqlsrv_query()`, you must check for errors and a false return value.  `if (!$res) print_r(sqlsrv_errors());`  Your input values are not escaped against SQL injection, so you may be running afoul of a query made invalid by that.  You should be using `?` placeholders instead of variables directly as in the documented examples http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php

Answer (score 0):

try this, it worked for me.

```
$sql="insert into almacen values(?,?,?,?,?)";
$params=array(
                array($pro,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array($pre,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array($alm,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array($cod,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array($exi,SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
               );
$options=array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
$res=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);
```

hope this helps you